# "Tor unexpectedly exited" Familiar message to many but no actual answers that I can find

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, windows, help

I have been using TOR with no issue but with the last update I have lost the ability to access it on any of my systems.

Every time I open TorBrowser on my systems running Win 10, it says "Tor unexpectedly exited. This might be due to a bug in Tor itself, another program on your system, or faulty hardware. Until you restart Tor, the Tor Browser will not be able to reach any websites. If the problem persists, please send a copy of your Tor Log to the support team."

When I try to restart it, it shows the same result. I tried to delete the TorBrowser data in Application Support but that does nothing. I tried to reinstall Tor in a different area other than Applications but that doesn't help. I can't copy a log to the clipboard because there are no logs therefore nothing to send to support team.

I have seen this question has been asked by several, both Win and Mac users, and either has no answer or the ones given are such gibberish as to be completely useless.
Does anyone have a clue as to an answer?

Comment: On Windows? This is probably antivirus or things like trusteer/webroot or other "security" software that's interfering with Tor Browser.

Comment: what is your windows 10 build? 32 or 64 bits? what antivirus and/or anti-malware software do you have installed?

Comment: Use Time machine - Restore latest working Tor browser - Non Update this - It's all

Answer (score 1):

1. Right click Tor Browser Icon
2. Click Properties
3. Top of Windows Click Compatibility tab
4. Click On Run compatibility troubleshooter.
   Wait a few seconds, your problem will be automaticaly fixed and you can work again with tor browser.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Try this, I searched everywhere for an answer but couldn't find one, anyways I clicked the checked file  and now TOR works

Comment: Given that manually launching `tor.exe` worked for you, I'd double down on my suggestion that this is caused by anti-virus or "security" software, since what normally happens is when Tor Browser starts, `firefox.exe` launches a copy of `tor.exe` and controls it. It seems something is blocking `firefox.exe` from launching `tor.exe`.